# Where can I find a List of Public DNS Servers/Resolvers

Tags: internet, domain-name-system

I am looking for a site or service that provides list of public DNS servers (or resolvers) around the world (besides Google/Opendns).

Answer (score 2):

[This looks good.](http://www.tech-faq.com/public-dns-servers.html)

Comment: Which leads to this excellent list: http://www.opennicproject.org/publictier2servers

Answer (score 0):

Part of [namebench](http://code.google.com/p/namebench/) includes benchmarking nameservers geographically near you.

You can find the list it uses at http://namebench.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/config/servers.csv but their FAQ indicates all of them [may not be entirely public](http://code.google.com/p/namebench/wiki/FAQ#Are_all_of_the_"regional_servers"_public?)